# Testing against multiple node module versions

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

I'm developing several node modules which extend the functionality of the [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) database ORM module. I'm using [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) to run tests before pushing new versions of my modules to NPM.

Travis allows you to run tests against different versions of node (v0.10, v0.12 etc). Similarly, I'd like to be able to run my tests using various different versions of the Sequelize module. i.e. run the tests once using Sequelize 2.0.0, again using 2.0.1, 2.0.2 etc.

Travis loads modules from NPM automatically according the the versions set in the package.json file, and so only runs tests using the latest module version available according to what's specified in the package.json of my module (in this case ^2.0.0).

Is there any way to interfere with this process and get Travis to run the tests multiple times using a different Sequelize version each time?

I've searched for advice on this on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but not had any luck. But I assume I can't be the only person who wants to do this...

Answer (score 4):

In the end the solution I came up with is to put the following in the travis.yml file:

```
before_script:
  - 'if [ "$SEQ_VERSION" ]; then npm install sequelize@^$SEQ_VERSION.0.0; fi'

env:
  - SEQ_VERSION=2
  - SEQ_VERSION=3
```

(with thanks to Sandro Munda for his answer which put me on the right track)

Answer (score 2):

In your `package.json`, you could have some something like this:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test-sequelize-2.0.0": "npm install sequelize@2.0.0 && ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
  "test-sequelize-2.1.0": "npm install sequelize@2.1.0 && ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
  "test": "npm run test-sequelize-2.0.0 && npm run test-sequelize-2.1.0"
}
...
```

Then, run `npm test`.

Answer (score 2):

[test-all-versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-all-versions) is a package that will run a command (you want your test script) for a whole range of semantic versions. so if you want to run your tests against sequelize you might write a config file like this.

```
#.tav.yml
name: sequelize
  versions: ^2.0.0
  command: npm run test
```

This will run your npm test script against all published versions of sequelize that match ^2.0.0 (ie 2.0.0, 2.0.1, etc)

Then in your travis config run the `tav` command to test against all versions in the given range.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)